# Get translation from matrix4()

Tags: three.js

It may look like a dummy question for most of the three.js developers but, how can a translation be extracted from the transformation matrix?

Actually I am extracting it manually pointing to the matrix array positions (12, 13, 14).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer I would prefer is to use `Vector3.setFromMatrixPosition( matrix4 )`.

Comment: This would be perfect, but does this method exists? If it does not, why? Maybe it makes too big the Matrix4 prototype?

Comment: DId you look at the docs? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3

Comment: Yes, but not at Vector3 but under Matrix4...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to extract the translation component from the matrix, then use this pattern:

```
var vec = new THREE.Vector3();
vec.setFromMatrixPosition( matrix4 );
```

Use `Matrix4.decompose()` only if you need the translation, quaternion and scale components.

three.js r.73

Comment: This is the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 5):

[`Matrix4` has a `decompose` method](http://threejs.org/docs/api/math/Matrix4.html#decompose) that is capable of exactly that.

```
var mat = /* ... */;
var translation = new THREE.Vector3(),
  rotation = new THREE.Quaternion(),
  scale = new THREE.Vector3();
mat.decompose(translation, rotation, scale);
```

Of course, if you are only interested in the translation then you are best off doing what you are currently doing. [Behind the scenes, `decompose` simply extracts elements 12, 13, and 14 from `mat.elements`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Matrix4.js#L890).

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer Brandon. Actually I was using the decompose function but not having initialized the vars to THREE.Vector3(), THREE.Quaternion and so on.