# THREE.js get local coordinate system of an object

Tags: javascript, three.js, system, local, coordinate

I am new in Three.js and need some help...

I am moving and rotating an object randomly several times. After certain time I need to know the orientation of the local coordinate system of that object to do some physics...

How do I extract from the object the matrix containing the local coordinate system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the matrix from your object in the property from your object3D called matrix.

Extracting the different information form this matrix is quite easy, follow the steps from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062579/get-translation-from-matrix4) or the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Matrix4)